# nginx ssl not working on Debian 8.7

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, debian

i try to setup a ssl connection with nginx and with a node server in the background. I alreday serached for hours but I can not figure out what is wrong with my nginx config. It works with curl `curl https://risiko-wirtschaft.at` but it does not work in the browser.

here the nginx config file:

```
server {
listen       443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name  risiko-wirtschaft.at;

ssl_certificate      cert/risiko-wirtschaft.at.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  cert/risiko-wirtschaft.at.key;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_ciphers  "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH !RC4";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

i also checked the Debian 8.7 firewall:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3850/nginx -g daemo
```

and `sudo nginx -t` returns

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

thanks!

Comment: i already figured out some more details and posted a new questions about this topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055427/nginx-ssl-neterr-connection-refused-debian

Comment: get sure of correct certificate relative paths

Comment: Hello Deadooshka, thanks for your comment, I have checked it but the same problem